# Php pdo simple htmldom sitemap multilanguage

Tags: php, html, xml

hello why is sitemap not in xml style? This error occurred after adding 'xhtml: link' and it prints out of loc.

What did I do? Where did I make a mistake? Can anyone fix it?

[image]

```
<?php
$pages = $db->from('pages')
//    ->select('pages.*, GROUP_CONCAT(languages.language_url SEPARATOR \' | \') as categories')
    ->join('page_categories', 'page_categories.category_id = pages.page_categories')
    ->join('languages', 'languages.language_url = pages.page_language')
    ->orderBy('page_id', 'ASC')
    ->groupBy('page_id')
    ->all();


$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$fonts = $doc->createElement('urlset');
$fonts->appendChild(new DomAttr('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'));
$fonts->appendChild(new DomAttr('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'));
$fonts->appendChild(new DomAttr('xmlns:xhtml', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'));
$fonts->appendChild(new DomAttr('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd 
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml  
http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd'));
    $entry = $doc->createElement("url");
    $entry->appendChild($doc->createElement('loc', site_maps("{$row['page_language']}/{$row['category_url']}/{$row['page_url']}")));
    $fonts->appendChild($entry);


    $entry = $doc->createElement('xhtml:link');
    $entry->setAttribute('rel', 'alternate');
    $entry->setAttribute('hreflang', $row['page_language']);
    $entry->setAttribute('href', site_maps("{$row['page_language']}/{$row['category_url']}/{$row['page_url']}"));
    $fonts->appendChild($entry);
}

$doc->appendChild($fonts);

header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo $doc->saveXML();
exit;
```

Comment: Think you're looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php

Comment: this is not what i am looking for